# Python requests receiving 404, wget gets proper page

Tags: python, http, python-requests, http-authentication

I am trying to retrieve a webpage which needs to be accessed from behind a proxy and additionally needs HTTP Authentication:

```
$ wget -d --user=atwood --ask-password http://example.com/admin/admin.php
```

This works fine, and will I paste the HTTP headers (request and response below).

Retrieving the same page with `python-requests` **returns a 404 error**:

Here is the Python code, which was preceded by the terrific method that user [Inactivist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1309774/inactivist) posted for [debugging the `requests` library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588644/how-can-i-see-the-entire-request-thats-being-sent-to-paypal-in-my-python-applic):

```
url = 'http://example.com/admin/admin.php'
proxy_config = {
    'http': '1.2.3.4',
    'https': '1.2.3.4',
    'ftp': '1.2.3.4'
}
head = {
    'User-Agent': 'Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)',
    'Connection': 'Close',
    'Proxy-Connection': 'Keep-Alive'
}

response = requests.get(url, auth=('atwood', 'hunter2'), proxies=proxy_config, headers=head)

print("Status code: %s" % (response.status_code, ))
print("URL: %s" % (response.url, ))
print(pformat(response.text))
```

Here are the `wget` HTTP headers (request and response), which **do in fact return the requested page properly**:

```
$ export http_proxy=http://1.2.3.4:3128
$ wget -d --user=atwood --ask-password  http://example.com/admin/admin.php
Setting --user (user) to atwood
Setting --ask-password (askpassword) to 1
Password for user `atwood': 
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.13.4 on linux-gnu.

URI encoding = `UTF-8'
URI encoding = `UTF-8'
--2014-01-07 11:15:59--  http://example.com/admin/admin.php
Host `example.com' has not issued a general basic challenge.
Connecting to 1.2.3.4:3128... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x000000000159bf20 (new refcount 0).
Deleting unused 0x000000000159bf20.

---request begin---
GET http://example.com/admin/admin.php HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: example.com
Connection: Close
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 
---response begin---
HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
Date: Tue, 07 Jan 2014 09:16:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Linux/SUSE)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="CONTACT-ADMIN"
Content-Length: 43
Content-Type: text/html
X-Cache: MISS from proxyServer
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from proxyServer:3128
Via: 1.0 proxyServer (squid/3.1.19)
Connection: keep-alive

---response end---
401 Unauthorized
Registered socket 3 for persistent reuse.
Skipping 43 bytes of body: [Login incorrect, please try again: |||BAD|
] done.
Inserted `example.com' into basic_authed_hosts
Reusing existing connection to 1.2.3.4:3128.
Reusing fd 3.

---request begin---
GET http://example.com/admin/admin.php HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: example.com
Connection: Close
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: Basic NjY2Njp0cmlwczEyMw==

---request end---
Proxy request sent, awaiting response...
---response begin---
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Tue, 07 Jan 2014 09:16:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Linux/SUSE)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Cache: MISS from proxyServer
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from proxyServer:3128
Via: 1.0 proxyServer (squid/3.1.19)
Connection: close

---response end---
200 OK
URI content encoding = `utf-8'
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `admin.php'

    [ <=>                            ] 14,096      --.-K/s   in 0.1s

2014-01-07 11:16:00 (92.8 KB/s) - `admin.php' saved [14096]
```

**You might notice that I have anonymized the URL that I am fetching. In fact, I have triple-checked that the URL which is returning 404 is in fact the same URL as that which works in `wget`.**

Comment: Is the difference in the proxy port just a result of anonymizing the URL?

Comment: `--user=atwood` ... I see what you did there.

Comment: You are right! I did not set the proxy port in Python!

Comment: @Evert: Please post your observation as an answer. You hit the nail right on the head.

Comment: @DaSourcerer: I wondered if any astute readers would notice that!

Comment: @dotancohen: Much to my own shame I didn't immediately grasp the hunter2 reference. A fellow TheDailyWTF reader, I suppose? :)

Comment: It's been a while since I've read TheDailyWTF, but there's a bash.org quote which I think is [the origin for `hunter2`](http://bash.org/?244321).

Comment: Well, for such a one-time mistake, it's a tad odd to put down an answer (very few other people will be helped by it), but it'll properly close the question. An other question remains: should an astute reader have noticed the various references, or the different proxy ports?

Comment: @Evert: The next person to Google it might be me :) As for the astute reader: I did mean only the in-jokes, but it definitely took an astute reader to notice the missing proxy port too!

Comment: @dotancohen That is indeed the origin. But it's getting repeatedly posted in the TDWTF comments, so I strongly link the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your proxy port in Python is not the same as used for wget (3128 versus the default 8080 I guess).