# Python requests authenticitation fails with get() despite successful post() login

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I want to login to a website and want to download some files from there afterwards. After some research I thought that using requests will do the trick. I've tried several approaches mentioned on SO and other sites but the result is always the same. After I successfully log in with `requests.post()` and want to download a file with requests.get(), I keep getting the `401 Authenticication Error`. The targeted urls are:

```
url_login = 'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home'
url_data = 'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products(\'09f4711b-05da-421c-9090-47b563ca75e9\')/$value'
```

Here's what I've tried:
#1

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth


req = requests.get(url_login, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'password'))
print(req.status_code)  # gets HTML code 200
data = requests.get(url_data)
print(data.status_code)  # gets HTML code 401
```

#2

```
import requests


credentials = dict(login='user', password='password')
session = requests.Session()

req = session.post(url_login, data=credentials)
print(req.status_code)  # gets HTML code 200
data = session.get(url_data)
print(data.status_code)  # gets HTML code 401
```

#3

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


session = requests.Session()
req = session.get(url_login, auth=(HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password')))
print(req.status_code)  # gets HTML code 200
data = session.get(url_data)
print(data.status_code)  # gets HTML code 401
```

What am I missing here?
I'm using Python 3.8 in an Conda environment.

Comment: Does [How to deal with 401 (unauthorised) in python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298860/how-to-deal-with-401-unauthorised-in-python-requests) answer your question?

Comment: @cs95 That solves the issue, thank you. But if it only needs the authentication within get(), what's the idea behind post()?