# requests.get causing 104 error under Linux but fine in Windows

Tags: python, https, python-requests, http-error, urllib3

I have a python script that logs in to a website and scrapes a few pages.

On my Windows machine which I wrote the script on this works fine but on my Linux machine which I was planning to run it on I'm getting `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))`

Linux machine works fine with http requests but it's falling over when I attempt to open the log in page through https.

I followed the example here [How can I see the entire HTTP request that's being sent by my Python application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588644/how-can-i-see-the-entire-http-request-thats-being-sent-by-my-python-application) and found that although I get debugging of the entire process under Windows the Linux machine only reports the first line `INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.example.com` and then I get the error.

I've stripped everything down and I'm still getting the error on Linux with a simple:

```
import requests
requests.get('https://www.example.com/Login')
```

Both machines are running the same version of python running on Windows 8 and CentOS

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Are you behind a proxy by any chance?

Comment: Sorry I haven't logged in for a while. No proxy, both machines are on the same network.