# Send raw POST request using Socket

Tags: python, sockets, http, webdriver

I am trying to send a raw `POST` request to a `chromedriver` server.

Here is what I try to initiate a `new session`:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(
    socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 9515))

s.send(b'POST /session HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type:application/json\r\n{"capabilities": {}, "desiredCapabilities": {}}\r\n\r\n')
response = s.recv(4096)
print(response)
```

Output:

```
b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length:270\r\nContent-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8\r\nConnection:close\r\n\r\n{"sessionId":"b26166c2aac022566917db20260500bb","status":33,"value":{"message":"session not created exception: Missing or invalid capabilities\\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Linux 4.4.0-91-generic x86_64)"}}'
```

Summary of error: `json` object I am sending is not getting parsed correctly

When I use the same `json` object but send it by `requests` library, everything is OK:

```
import requests

params = {
        'capabilities': {},
        'desiredCapabilities': {}
    }


headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

URL = "http://127.0.0.1:9515"

r = requests.post(URL + "/session", json=params)

print("Status: " + str(r.status_code))
print("Body: " + str(r.content))
```

Output:

```
Status: 200
Body: b'{"sessionId":"e03189a25d099125a541f3044cb0ee42","status":0,"value":{"acceptSslCerts":true,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"browserName":"chrome","chrome":{"chromedriverVersion":"2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8)","userDataDir":"/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.LBeQkw"},"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"handlesAlerts":true,"hasTouchScreen":false,"javascriptEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":true,"mobileEmulationEnabled":false,"nativeEvents":true,"networkConnectionEnabled":false,"pageLoadStrategy":"normal","platform":"Linux","rotatable":false,"setWindowRect":true,"takesHeapSnapshot":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"unexpectedAlertBehaviour":"","version":"60.0.3112.90","webStorageEnabled":true}}'
```

Summary of output: `json` object is parsed successfully by the `chromedriver` and `new session` is created

Do you, guys, have an idea why sending the raw `POST` request using `socket` is not working as expected?

Comment: Well, you misspelled "Content" in you POST.

Comment: Hi @JamesKPolk I fixed it, sorry. It is still behaving the same way though.

Comment: You can log what `requests` actually sends and reuse it with sockets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588644/how-can-i-see-the-entire-http-request-thats-being-sent-by-my-python-application

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several issues about your HTTP request:

- The body of the HTTP request should be separated from the head by `\r\n\r\n`.
- You need the `Content-Length` field, otherwise the remote host does not know when your body is complete.
- The `Host` field is mandatory in HTTP 1.1. (Since you receive `200` with your first request, your server probably doesn't insist.)

I've got your example to work (with an apache webserver) by using:

```
s.send(b'POST /session HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1:9515\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 47\r\n\r\n{"capabilities": {}, "desiredCapabilities": {}}')
```

To be visually more clear, the valid `HTTP` request looks like

```
POST /session HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:9515
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 47

{"capabilities": {}, "desiredCapabilities": {}}
```