# python requests.put() fails when urllib3 http.request('PUT', ...) succeeds. What gives?

Tags: python, python-requests, confluence-rest-api

I am trying to hit the Atlassian Confluence REST API using python requests.

I've successfully called a GET api, but when I call the PUT to update a confluence page, it returns 200, but didn't update the page.

I used chrome::YARC to verify that the API was working properly (which it was). After a while trying to debug it, I reverted to try using urllib3, which worked just fine.

I'd really like to use requests, but I can't for the life of me figure this one out after hours and hours of trying to debug, Google, etc.

I'm running Mac/Python3:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin mylaptop.local 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.1
```

Here's my code that shows all three ways I'm trying this (two requests and one urllib3):

```
def update(self, spaceKey, pageTitle, newContent, contentType='storage'):
    if contentType not in ('storage', 'wiki', 'plain'):
        raise ValueError("Invalid contentType={}".format(contentType))

    # Get current page info
    self._refreshPage(spaceKey, pageTitle) # I retrieve it before I update it.
    orig_version = self.version

    # Content already same as requested content. Do nothing
    if self.wiki == newContent:
        return

    data_dict = {
        'type' : 'page',
        'version' : {'number' : self.version + 1},
        'body'  : {
            contentType : {
                'representation' : contentType,
                'value' : str(newContent)
            }
        }
    }
    data_json = json.dumps(data_dict).encode('utf-8')

    put = 'urllib3' #for now until I figure out why requests.put() doesn't work
    enable_http_logging()
    if put == 'requests':
        r = self._cs.api.content(self.id).PUT(json=data_dict)
        r.raise_for_status()
    elif put == 'urllib3':
        urllib3.disable_warnings() # I know, you can quit your whining now!!!
        headers = { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json;charset=utf-8' }
        auth_header = urllib3.util.make_headers(basic_auth=":".join(self._cs.session.auth))
        headers = {**headers, **auth_header}
        http = urllib3.PoolManager()
        r = http.request('PUT', str(self._cs.api.content(self.id)), body=data_json, headers=headers)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Huh? Unknown put type: {}".format(put))
    enable_http_logging(False)

    # Verify page was updated
    self._refreshPage(spaceKey, pageTitle) # Check for changes
    if self.version != orig_version + 1:
        raise RuntimeError("Page not updated. Still at version {}".format(self.version))
    if self.wiki != newContent:
        raise RuntimeError("Page version updated, but not content.")
```

Any help would be great.

### Update 1: Adding request dump

```
-----------START-----------
PUT http://confluence.myco.com/rest/api/content/101904815
User-Agent: python-requests/2.18.4
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 141
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic <auth-token-here>==

b'{"type": "page", "version": {"number": 17}, "body": {"storage": {"representation": "storage", "value": "new body here version  version 17"}}}'
```

Comment: I've used this guy example in the past and it worked great - https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-to-update-a-page-with-Python-using-REST-API/qaq-p/480627. you can look around if he did something different.

Comment: Ahh... don't shadow your `data`... when using `data=` or `json=` give it the `dict` object - *not* the JSON `str` representation...

Comment: Thanks @droravr. That's actually what I used as the starting point for my script. Just to make sure, I just grabbed his original code off the link you gave and ran it again. I'm having the same problems with his code.

Comment: @davfive does `requests.put(url, auth=self.m_auth, json=data)` where `data` is your dictionary of data and not the JSON string work?

Comment: @JonClements, so I believe you're suggesting to just pass the data without running it through json.dumps(). I just tried that with the same results.

Comment: @davfive using `json=` or `data=` ?

Comment: @JonClements, no, using json= instead of data= doesn't help any. Interesteingly, if I do a dump of the response.history[0].request, everything seems to be there ok. See above in my question, I've added the request dump.

Comment: @davfive yeah... it should just work using `json=` and letting that do the headers for you... I suspect something else is making you think it's not working... but there should be nothing wrong with the above `requests.put`...

Comment: @JonClements, what's making me think it's not working is that I go to the confluence page after the script is run and it's not updated, only when i use urllib3

Comment: @davfive can't you set what you're updating to some obvious non-value like  999999999 or whatever and then check the page... (sometimes it's easy to lose track of incrementing by 1 whether it you were expecting 1 or 2)

Comment: @JonClements, good thought and sure I could do that, but I'm setting the page number to the confluence version number for what the new page should be, so it's easy to check. Also, I have the checkbody code at the end of the method which regrabs the page and checks if the page has the expected new data. I'm not misreading whether the page is being updated.

Comment: Can you upload the response? btw, does it work with a `"representation": "wiki"`?

Comment: Please don't edit the question to mark it as "solved". Post an actual answer and mark it as acoepted.

Comment: @triplee, sorry about that. I've moved my "solved comment" down below. In the meantime Kos answered it from the RFC and I've marked his as selected answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> requests never went back to PUT (Bug???)

What you're observing is `requests` behaving consistently with web browsers: reacting to HTTP 302 redirect with a GET request.

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302):

> The user agent (e.g. a web browser) is invited by a response with this code to make a second, otherwise identical, request to the new URL specified in the location field.
>
> (...)
>
> Many web browsers implemented this code in a manner that violated this standard, changing the request type of the new request to GET, regardless of the type employed in the original request (e.g. POST)
>
> (...)
>
> **As a consequence, the update of RFC 2616 changes the definition to allow user agents to rewrite POST to GET.**

So this behaviour is consistent with RFC 2616. I don't think we can say which of the two libraries behaves "more correctly".

Comment: Nice. Thanks. I've moved my "solved" section from the main question to an answer and marked yours as the answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a difference in how the requests and urllib3 modules deal with switching from http to https. (See @Kos answer above). Here's what I found when I checked the debug logs.

So I got to thinking after @JonClements suggested I send him the Response dump. After doing some research I found the magic runs to enable debugging for requests and urllib3 (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588644/how-can-i-see-the-entire-http-request-thats-being-sent-by-my-python-application)).

In looking at the diffs from both, I noticed that they were being redirected from http to https for my companies confluence site:

urllib3:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): confluence.myco.com
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://confluence.myco.com:80 "PUT /rest/api/content/101906196 HTTP/1.1" 302 237
DEBUG:urllib3.util.retry:Incremented Retry for (url='http://confluence.myco.com/rest/api/content/101906196'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
INFO:urllib3.poolmanager:Redirecting 
    http://confluence.myco.com/rest/api/content/101906196 -> 
    https://confluence.myco.com/rest/api/content/101906196
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): confluence.myco.com
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://confluence.myco.com:443 "PUT /rest/api/content/101906196 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

while requests tried with my PUT and then after redirecting went to GET:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://confluence.myco.com:80 "PUT /rest/api/content/101906196 HTTP/1.1" 302 237
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://confluence.myco.com:443 "GET /rest/api/content/101906196 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

requests never went back to PUT

I changed my initial url from http: to https: and everything worked fine.