# How to examine POST request data sent from python3 script in IntelliJ

Tags: python-3.x, post, intellij-idea, https, postdata

I have a simple python3 script, using the requests package to send a POST request to an URL through https. I would like to find a way to check the content of the request sent, specifically I am interested in the data sent.
Optimally I would like to get a way doing it from IntelliJ, but I'm interested in any other option too.
I tried using Wireshark, but I don't seem to succeed, as it's https.
I don't own the server, so there's no way to monitor it on the server.
OS: Linux Mint 18.2

Comment: How about changing the URL you're sending the data to? For instance, you could run your own web server for development purposes that logs all incoming requests.

Comment: Did you try http://www.telerik.com/fiddler ?

Comment: Thank you both! I think both are feasible ways, but in the end I found the exact solution I needed. :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588644/how-can-i-see-the-entire-http-request-thats-being-sent-by-my-python-application