# Python3 Requests Module using Config Parameter for Logging

Tags: python-3.x, logging, python-requests, stderr, verbose

Is there a way to enable the verbose mode over requests library on python over config parameter using logging module?

Here is the example using config but to redirect to stderr.

```
    my_config = {'verbose': sys.stderr}
    requests.get('http://httpbin.org/headers', config=my_config)
    2011-08-17T03:04:23.380175   GET   http://httpbin.org/headers
```

[Example from the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.6/user/advanced/#verbose-logging)

I know that there is a way to use the debug logging [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588644/how-can-i-see-the-entire-http-request-thats-being-sent-by-my-python-application) but the idea is to use the new configuration provided.