# Is there a way to get the breakdown of an API response time in *Python* similar to what we can get from Postman?

Tags: python, python-requests

Is there a way to get the breakdown of the response-time of a API request call from **Python** (Requests module) or in **LocustIO** load testing tool.

I have two requirements where I would like to report the TransferStart part alone. Is there something I can do to get a better break down of the round trip time. Currently I am doing the following:

```
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    r = requests.get(api_url, headers=token, verify=False)
    elapsed_time = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
```

[Postman - break down of an API response time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqvcY.png)

Comment: well you can increase the verbosity of the requests module log like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588644/how-can-i-see-the-entire-http-request-thats-being-sent-by-my-python-application)

Comment: Where can I find the time taken for SocketInitialization, TCP handshake, SSL Handshake, TransferStart (which I need to report) and Download time?