Why does Python Requests module triggers bot detection logic on this website?
I am trying to fetch a website. It works in the browser, and works in curl, but throws 403 in Python (which comes along with a CAPTCHA, but that is irrelevant as I am trying to find the difference between Python requests and other libraries).
Similar questions have been asked before, but I have taken those recommendations and done additional analysis, so hopefully someone from Python community can help as this remains an unsolved issue.
This works:
curl -v --http1.1 -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:127.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/127.0" https://www.kron4.com/

> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.kron4.com
> Accept: */*
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:127.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/127.0

HTTP 2 works too:
curl -v -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:127.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/127.0" https://www.kron4.com/

> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: www.kron4.com
> Accept: */*
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:127.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/127.0

Python request miserably fails even when I match the header.
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:127.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/127.0'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status()  

>File "/Users/xxxxx/Documents/workspace/NewsFu/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 1024, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://www.kron4.com/


I know python adds a couple of things like Accept, but I don't think that is an issue as browser adds them too. It supports only HTTP/1.1 that's why I tried it with curl. At this point I am thinking that maybe header is not the issue and the website is detecting something else unusual in python request. But what it is beats me because everything is encrypted. Otherwise I could use wireshark to disect it further. Any ideas are welcome.

Could be TLS fingerprinting.

your curl command gives me 403 and the same HTML as for requests. with title "Access to this page has been denied"

Thanks @furas. This mean that my comparing with curl is probably futile. There are other parameters. curl continue to work for me.

@NickODell if you could post it as an answer, I would accept it. I verified that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60407057/python-requests-being-fingerprinted works for me.
