# how to process output from python-gitlab api requests

Tags: python-gitlab

for instance the call
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('http://192.168.2.175', private_token=run_args['my_token'])

```
projects = gl.projects.list()
for project in projects:
    print(project)
```

produces output that cannot be processed as json. What is the process for parsing this information or should i just used standard rest requests and abandon python-gitlab?

<class 'gitlab.v4.objects.Project'> => {u'lfs_enabled': True, u'forks_count': 0, u'autoclose_referenced_issues': True, ...  u'avatar_url': None, u'auto_cancel_pending_pipelines': u'enabled', u'jobs_enabled': True}

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to troubleshoot more. I have tested out the following set up, which is similar to yours, and gl.projects.list() returns a json list of the projects.

```
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.com/', ACCESS_TOKEN)

def get_projects():
    projects = gl.projects.list(owned=True)
    for project in projects:
        print(project.name)
```

(python-gitlab uses requests "under the hood" https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab#requirements)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for which I was looking. The results are a class dictionary:
projects = gl.projects.list(search='autobuild')
for project in projects:
for item in project.**dict**['_attrs']:
print item

This produces the list of variables pertinent to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be, convert the project object into a **dictionary**.

```
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.com/', ACCESS_TOKEN)

def get_projects():
    projects = gl.projects.list(owned=True)
    for project in projects:
        project = project.attributes
        print(project["name"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `python-gitlab` is working under the hood with `requests` you can just enable debug logs for it, described in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588644/how-can-i-see-the-entire-http-request-thats-being-sent-by-my-python-application)

Just answering to this quite old question, because I had the same problem today :)