# Python String format for URLs

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to post a payload to a rest endpoint using the python requests library and having an issue with the formatting of the endpoint. The below code works:

```
endpoint="https://api.something/path/to/my/endpoint"
headers= {"Authorization": "Bearer <token>"}

req = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, data).json()
```

However I were to change the endpoint to something like this

```
my_var="my"
endpoint="https://api.something/path/to/{}/endpoint".format(my_var)
```

My post request no longer works giving me a `not found` . In both cases the endpoint resolves to the exact same URL but yet using `format` doesnt seem to work.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Hi, perhaps enable tracing to verify the full request https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588644/how-can-i-see-the-entire-http-request-thats-being-sent-by-my-python-application

Comment: Hello, can you give details regarding: 1. The exact error 2. The exact url of the request? Normally, this works fine for me: `"https://api.something/path/to/"+my_var+"/endpoint"`