# Twitter API query hashtag

Tags: python, api, twitter

I'm trying to collect tweet data which has specific hashtag by using twitter api.

I use the python code below.

https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/master/Recent-Search/recent_search.py

It does work seemingly.

However, when I change the line 14 from

```
query = "from:twitterdev -is:retweet"
```

to

```
query = "#apple"
```

it does not work anymore.
Error message is below.

```
Exception: (400, '{"errors":[{"parameters":{"query":[""]},"message":"Invalid \'query\':\'\'. \'query\' must be a non-empty string"}],"title":"Invalid Request","detail":"One or more parameters to your request was invalid.","type":"https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/invalid-request"}')
```

It seems to relate #. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
query = "%23apple"
```

In Twitter's sample code, the variable `query` is used as a parameter of the URL. Certain characters are not allowed in the parameter of an URL (like `/`, `?`, `#` etc.).

The URL `https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=#apple` is invalid.
`%23` is the encoded value of #. The URL will look like this: `https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=%23apple`.

The Twitter API then can `%23` translate back into `#`.

Here is a in-depth explanation: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to troubleshoot what might be going on here. A couple of suggestions.

1. Check out [this page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query).
2. In line 39, remove the `.json()` from `response.json()` and run the code again. Once you've done that, you can troubleshoot your code in the interactive command-line very of Python.

To be clear, go to your terminal, enter Python, and then load your functions one by one (Except `main()`). Then go through the code in `main()` code one line at a time. After you run `json_response = connect_to_endpoint(url, headers)` you should still get an error, however, you can then use the objects in the `response.request` object to see what is going on. For example, after doing the above and then running...

```py
response = connect_to_endpoint(url, headers)
```

...you can then execute `response.request.url` to print the full URL that was sent to Twitter and compare it to the form of that found in the *Building queries* page linked above.

See the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588644/how-can-i-see-the-entire-http-request-thats-being-sent-by-my-python-application) for a nice list of what is available. You can also (after running `response = connect_to_endpoint(url, headers)`) simply type `response.request.` (include both periods) into your terminal and then press the `shift` key a couple of times to make your terminal print these options.

Comment: Thank you!! This (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66816892/14084128) works!!