# requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error atlassian-python-api

Tags: python, confluence, confluence-rest-api, atlassian-python-api

I am trying to connect to a Confluence page using the python wrapper on the API (as I am not familiar with any of this) but I keep getting the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error
```

I know that people talk about this being caused by the necessity of using an API token but the page runs on an old version of Confluence and I have been told that we cannot use access tokens.

So has anyone any other idea? Here's a small code:

```
from atlassian import Confluence

confluence = Confluence(
    url='https://address',
    username='name',
    password='pwd'
    )

confluence.create_page(
    space='Test',
    title='A title',
    body='something')
```

I have tried to use an older version of `atlassian-python-api` just in case there was some conflict but it got me the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks ok. Authenticating to Confluence using Basic Auth should work without generating an API token, afaik.

The `401` status definitely suggests a problem with the authentication though. The obvious reason for this would be of course wrong credentials, but I assume that you have double checked that the credentials work when interactively logging into confluence with a browser.

To get a better sense of the error, you can `import logging` to debug your requests and response:

```
from atlassian import Confluence
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='conf_connect.log', filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)

try: 
    c = Confluence(url='https://conf.yoursystem.com', username='name', password='pwd')
    # atlassian API does not raise error on init if credentials are wrong, this only happens on the first request
    c.get_user_details_by_username('name')

except Exception as e:
    logging.error(e)
```

The `Confluence` module internally also uses `logging`, so the requests and responses will appear in your `conf_connect.log` logfile:

```
DEBUG:atlassian.rest_client:curl --silent -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json'  'https://conf.yoursystem.com/rest/api/user?username=name'
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): conf.yoursystem.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://conf.yoursystem.com:443 "GET /rest/api/user?username=name HTTP/1.1" 401 751
DEBUG:atlassian.rest_client:HTTP: GET rest/api/user -> 401 
DEBUG:atlassian.rest_client:HTTP: Response text -> <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 401 – Unauthorized</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 401 – Unauthorized</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Message</b> Basic Authentication Failure - Reason : AUTHENTICATED_FAILED</p><p><b>Description</b> The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/9.0.33</h3></body></html>
ERROR:root:401 Client Error:  for url: https://conf.yoursystem.com/rest/api/user?username=name
```

The response body may include some information on the reason:

> ## HTTP Status 401 – Unauthorized
>
> **Type** Status Report
>
> **Message** Basic Authentication Failure - Reason : AUTHENTICATED_FAILED
>
> **Description** The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

The reason `AUTHENTICATED_FAILED` suggests something is likely wrong with your credentials. If you want to dig deeper into that, you can use [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16630836/14015737) to also display the headers that are being sent with your request.

However, if your reason is `AUTHENTICATION_DENIED` the problem is likely the following: If you have too many failed authentication attempts in a row, a  CAPTCHA challenge is triggered, and this error will occur until the *Failed Login Count* is reset. This can easily happen when you are developing a script and test it frequently. To remedy this, either open a browser and manually (re-)logon to Confluence, completing the CAPTCHA, or [resolve it from the Confluence User Management](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/authentication_denied-error-when-accessing-confluence-content-via-rest-api-call-966681459.html).