# scraping python requests soraredata

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, python-requests

Hello I am trying to retrieve the json of soraredata by this link but it returns me a source code without json.
When I put this link in a software called Insomnia it happens to have the json so I think it must be possible with requests?
sorry for my english i use the translator.

edit : the link seems to work without the "my_username" so `url = "https://www.soraredata.com/api/stats/newFullRankings/all/false/all/7/0/sr_football"`

I get a status code 403, I don't know what is missing to get 200?

Thank you

```
headers = {
    "Host" : "www.soraredata.com",    
    "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0",
    "Referer" : "https://www.soraredata.com/rankings",
    }

#url = "https://www.soraredata.com/api/stats/newFullRankings/all/false/all/7/{my_username}/0/sr_football"

res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
html = res.text
#html = json.loads(html)    

print(html)
```

Comment: 403 means authorization is needed. Is that a public API that you can use freely?

Comment: I don't know at all I don't know much about it unfortunately, I have the impression that in the source code it talks about captcha but I never seen it on the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution I got to work.

```py
import http.client
import json
import socket
import ssl
import urllib.request

hostname = "www.soraredata.com"
path = "/api/stats/newFullRankings/all/false/all/7/0/sr_football"
http_msg = "GET {path} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {host}\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nUser-Agent: python-urllib3/1.26.7\r\n\r\n".format(
    host=hostname,
    path=path
).encode("utf-8")

sock = socket.create_connection((hostname, 443), timeout=3.1)
context = ssl.create_default_context()

with sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
        ssock.sendall(urllib3_msg)
        response = http.client.HTTPResponse(ssock, method="GET")
        response.begin()
        print(response.status, response.reason)
        data = response.read()

resp_data = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

What was perplexing is that the HTTP message I used was the exact same one used by [urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), as indicated when debugging the following code. (See the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16630836) for how to set up logging to debug requests, which also works for urllib3.)

Yet, this code gave a 403 HTTP status code.

```py
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

r = http.request(
    "GET",
    "https://www.soraredata.com/api/stats/newFullRankings/all/false/all/7/0/sr_football",
)
assert r.status == 403
```

Moreover `http.client` also gave a 403 status code, and it seems to be doing pretty much what I did above: wrap a socket in an SSL context and send the request.

```py
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(hostname)
conn.request("GET", path)
res = conn.getresponse()
assert res.status == 403
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you ogdenkev!

I also found this but it doesn't always work

```
import cloudscraper
import json
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
r = scraper.get(url,).text 
y = json.loads(r)
print (y)
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for sharing. It makes sense that Cloudfare was denying the request based on something that requests or urllib3 were doing. I just wasn't able to figure out what that was.